# Alternative to "ntile" for MySQL version lower than 8?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying the below code, which analyses and scores customers based on recency, frequency and monetary value of transactions.

```
select customer_id, rfm_recency, rfm_frequency, rfm_monetary

from 
    (
        select customer_id,
            ntile(4) over (order by last_order_date) as rfm_recency,
            ntile(4) over (order by count_order) as rfm_frequency,
            ntile(4) over (order by sum_amount) as rfm_monetary


    from 

        (
           select customer_id,
               max(local_date) as last_order_date,
               count(*) as count_order,
               sum(amount) as sum_amount
           from transaction
           group by customer_id) as T

        ) as P
```

However `ntile` is not available in my MySQL version (v5) as apparently it's a "window function" which works on v8+ only.

I can't find a working alternative to this function. I am very new to SQL so I'm having a hard time figuring it out myself.

Is there an `ntile` alternative that I can use? The code works fine if i remove the `ntile` segment.

Comment: The query is possible, but it will be too complex. You must enumerate  rows over needed ordering (separately for each ordering!), get rows count, then calculate ntile. I'd recommend SP form for to solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

You should really upgrade to MySQL 8.0 if you need features in MySQL 8.0. They are bound to be easier and more optimized.

I found a way to simulate the ntile query shown in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile):

```
SELECT
 val,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS 'row_number',
 NTILE(2)     OVER w AS 'ntile2',
 NTILE(4)     OVER w AS 'ntile4'
FROM numbers
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY val);
```

Here's a solution:

```
SELECT val, @r:=@r+1 AS rownum, 
 FLOOR((@r-1)*2/9)+1 AS ntile2, 
 FLOOR((@r-1)*4/9)+1 AS ntile4 
FROM (SELECT @r:=0,@n:=0) AS _init, numbers
```

The 2 and 4 factors are for the ntile(2) and ntile(4) respectively. The 9 value is because there are 9 rows in this example table. You must know the count of the table before you can run this query. The solution also requires user defined variables, which are always kind of tricky.

Result:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| val  | rownum | ntile2 | ntile4 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
|    1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |
|    1 |      2 |      1 |      1 |
|    2 |      3 |      1 |      1 |
|    3 |      4 |      1 |      2 |
|    3 |      5 |      1 |      2 |
|    3 |      6 |      2 |      3 |
|    4 |      7 |      2 |      3 |
|    4 |      8 |      2 |      4 |
|    5 |      9 |      2 |      4 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to adapt this technique to your query and your table, or to decide that it's time to upgrade to MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Will give this a go. Unfortunately the upgrade is out of my control. I have to work with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate rows and use arithmetic.  Unfortunately, you'll need to do this three times:

```
select floor(seqnum * 4 / @rn) as ntile_recency, t.*
from (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum, t.*
      from (select customer_id, max(local_date) as last_order_date, count(*) as count_order,
                   sum(amount) as sum_amount
            from transaction
            group by customer_id
            order by last_order_date
           ) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t;
```